# Skipping ad on iOS doesn't work

Tags: ios, jwplayer

According to the JWplayer documentation this should work, but I can't see any skip button when playing ads.

```
//ad config
JWAdConfig *adConfig = [JWAdConfig new];
adConfig.adMessage = @"Ad duration countdown xx";
adConfig.skipMessage = @"Skip in xx";
adConfig.skipText = @"Move on";
adConfig.skipOffset = 3;
adConfig.adClient = vastPlugin;
config.adConfig = adConfig;
```

Also asking JWplayer: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/questions/16078471-skipping-ad-on-ios-doesn-t-work?new=16078471

@Max Mikheyenko - the ad url:

```
NSString *appBundle = @"myBundleName";
NSString *appDomain = @"myDomainName";
NSString *appName = @"myAppName";

NSString *adUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://search.myadurl.com/vast/2.0/myadurlid?VPAID=JS&app[name]=%@&app[domain]=%@&app[bundle]=%@&device[ifa]=%@", appName, appDomain, appBundle, kGaPropertyId];

config.adSchedule = @[[JWAdBreak adBreakWithTag:adUrl offset:@"pre"]];
```

@Max Mikheyenko - VPAID=js

JWplayer recently told my colleague (He is implementing the same for Android) that JW player in app doesn't support VPAID 2.0 (JS) and asked him to change the URL with replacing VPAID=js to VPI=MP4.

Recent update: I tried it again with VPI=MP4 and now I'm getting this error

```
2016-01-10 15:05:07.346 [21:285288] AD ERROR {
    adposition = pre;
    client = vast;
    code = 101;
    event = onAdError;
    message = "Ad Tag Empty";
```

@Max Mikheyenko

VPI=MP4 now works fine, I accidentally added a dollar sign to my url when replacing VPAID=JS with VPI=MP4

Comment: so the ad works but there is no skip button? url you posted doesn't work, and JWPlayer ios SDK does not support VPAID (there is 'vpaid' in your url)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko I've added some more details about VPAID vs. VPI in my question

Comment: as i said - i'll need an ad tag that i can test with - one provided didn't work - kGaPropertyId is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With VPI=MP4 it works fine!

VPAID=JS did work for iOS but without the skip button, and VPI=MP4 now shows the skip button.